# RandomNum is undefined, and I don't understand why

Tags: javascript

I took this script tutorial from [here](https://www.mybloggertricks.com/2016/06/recent-posts-gadget.html), and I tried to combine the random function from this similar tutorial [here](https://www.mybloggertricks.com/2016/07/random-posts-widget-for-blogger.html), except make it a setting, and it says RandomNum is undefined. Why, and how do I fix it?

Javascript:

```
/*** LET'S ADD THE VARIABLE SETTINGS. TO TOGGLE USE TRUE/FALSE ***/
var domainURL = window.location.hostname;
var className = "default";
var postCount = 3;
var showPostLabel = "test";
var showPostContentAmount = 160;
var showPostTitle = "true";
var showPostTitleAmount = 80;
var showInPostImageSize = 320;
var showPostComments = "true";
var showPostDate = "true";
var showPostAuthor = "true";
var showPostImage = "true";
var showPostCategory = "true";
var showPostTags = "true";
var showPostContent = "true";
var showCategoryArchive = "true";
var showRandomPosts = "true";

/*** LET'S GENERATE RANDOM POSTS ***/
if (showRandomPosts == 'true')
{
  var RandomArray = [];
  var TotalPosts  = 0;
  var RandomArray = new Array(postCount);
  
  function TotalCount(json)
  {
    TotalPosts   = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;
  }
  document.write('<script src="https://'+domainURL+'/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=TotalCount"></'+'script>');

  function GenerateNum()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < postCount ; i++)
    {
      for (var j = 0; j < RandomArray.length; j++)
      {
        var RandomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (TotalPosts ) + 1);
        RandomArray[i] = RandomNum; 
      }
    }
  }
}

/*** LET'S START THE POST LIST ***/
function jsonposts(json)
{
  document.write('<ul class="json-posts '+className+'">');
  for (var i = 0; i < postCount; i++)
  {
    /*** LET'S DECLARE VARIABLES ***/
    var postVariables= postImage = postUrl = postTitle = postImage = postContent = postArticle = postAuthor = postLabel = postDate = postUpdated = postComment = postImageURL = postCategoryArchive = postImageURLSize = postAuthorImage = postDateFormat = Y = D = M = m = YY = DD = MM = mm = TT =  "";

    /*** LET'S GET THE POST LABELS ***/
    if (json.feed.entry[i].category != null)
    {
      for (var k = 0; k < json.feed.entry[i].category.length; k++) 
      {
        postLabel += '<a class="json-post-article-tags-item" href="'+domainURL+'/search/label/'+json.feed.entry[i].category[k].term+'">'+json.feed.entry[i].category[k].term+'</a>';
        if(k < json.feed.entry[i].category.length-1)
        { 
          postLabel += '<span class="json-post-article-tags-item-seperator">, </span>';
        }
      }
    }

    /*** LET'S GET THE POST URL ***/
    for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) 
    {
      if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate') 
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    postUrl= '"' + json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href + '"';

    /*** LET'S GET THE POST INFO ***/
    postCategoryArchive = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;

    /*** LET'S GET THE POST TITLE ***/
    if (json.feed.entry[i].title!= null)
    {
      postTitle= json.feed.entry[i].title.$t.substr(0, showPostTitleAmount);
    }

    /*** LET'S GET THE POST COMMENT COUNT ***/
    if (json.feed.entry[i].thr$total)
    {
      postComment= '<a href="'+json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href+'#comment-form">'+json.feed.entry[i].thr$total.$t+'</a>';
    }

    /*** LET'S GET THE POST AUTHOR INFO ***/
    postAuthor= json.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t.split(' ');
    postAuthor=postAuthor.slice(0, 1).join(' ');
    postAuthorImage = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].gd$image.src;

    /*** LET'S GET THE POST CONTENT ***/
    postArticle = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
    postContent= postArticle.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'').substring(0, showPostContentAmount);

    /*** LET'S FORMAT THE POST DATE MONTH ***/
    postDateFormat= ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    /*** LET'S GET THE POST DATE ***/
    postDate= json.feed.entry[i].published.$t.substring(0,10);

    /*** LET'S DO THE POST DATE FORMAT ***/
    Y = postDate.substring(0, 4);
    m = postDate.substring(5, 7);
    D = postDate.substring(8, 10);
    M = postDateFormat[parseInt(m - 1)];

    /*** LET'S GET THE UPDATED POST DATE ***/
    postUpdated= json.feed.entry[i].updated.$t.substring(0, 16);

    /*** LET'S DO THE UPDATED POST DATE FORMAT ***/
    YY = postUpdated.substring(0, 4);
    mm = postUpdated.substring(5, 7);
    DD = postUpdated.substring(8, 10);
    TT = postUpdated.substring(11, 16);
    MM = postDateFormat[parseInt(mm - 1)];

    /*** LET'S GET THE POST IMAGE ***/
    if (json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail)
    {
      postImageURL = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
      postImageURLSize= postImageURL.replace("/s72-c/","/s"+showInPostImageSize+"/");
      postImage= "'" + postImageURLSize.replace("?imgmax=800","") + "'";
    }

    /*** LET'S ADD VARIOUS IMAGE TYPE SUPPORT***/
    else if (json.feed.entry[i].content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/) != null)
    {
      postImage =  json.feed.entry[i].content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/)[1];
    }

    /*** LET'S OPEN THE POST ARTICLE ***/
    document.write('<li class="json-post-article-'+[i]+'">');

    /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST CATEGORY ***/
    if (showPostCategory == 'true')
    {
      document.write('<div class="json-post-article-tags"><span class="json-post-article-tags-label"></span>'+postLabel+'</div>');
    }

    /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST IMAGE ***/
    if (showPostImage == 'true')
    {
      document.write('<a class="json-post-article-featured-image-link" href="'+postUrl+'"><figure class="json-post-article-featured-image" style="background: url('+postImage+') no-repeat center center / cover !important"></figure></a>');
    }

    /*** LET'S OPEN THE POST INFO BOX ***/
    document.write('<div>');

    /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST TITLE ***/
    if (showPostTitle == 'true')
    {
      document.write('<h4 class="json-post-article-title"><a class="json-post-article-title-link" href="'+postUrl+'">'+postTitle+'</a></h4>');
    }

    /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST AUTHOR ***/
    if (showPostAuthor == 'true')
    {
      document.write('<span class="json-post-article-author-label"></span><figure class="json-post-article-author-avatar" style="background: url(https:'+postAuthorImage+') no-repeat center center /cover !important"></figure><span class="json-post-article-author-avatar">'+postAuthor+'</span>');
    }

    /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST DATE ***/
    if (showPostDate == 'true')
    {
      document.write('<div class="json-post-article-date"><span class="json-post-article-date-label"></span><span class="json-post-article-date-month">'+M+'</span> <span class="json-post-article-date-day">'+D+'</span> <span class="json-post-article-date-year">'+Y+'</span></div>');
    }

    /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST CONTENT ***/
    if (showPostContent == 'true')
    {
      document.write('<p class="json-post-article-content">'+postContent+'...</p>');
    }

    /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST TAGS ***/
    if (showPostTags == 'true')
    {
      document.write('<div class="json-post-article-tags"><span class="json-post-article-tags-label"></span>'+postLabel+'</div>');
    }

    /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST COMMENT COUNT ***/
    if (showPostComments == 'true')
    {
      document.write('<div class="json-post-article-comment-count"><span class="json-post-article-comment-count-label">Comments: </span><span class="json-post-article-comment-count-number">'+postComment+'</span></div>');
    }

    /*** LET'S CLOSE THE POST INFO BOX ***/
    document.write('</div>');

    /*** LET'S CLOSE THE POST ARTICLE ***/
    document.write('</li>');

  }
  
  /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST CATEGORY ARCHIVE LINK ***/
  if (showCategoryArchive == 'true')
  {
    document.write('<a class="json-post-article-category-more" href="'+domainURL+'/search/label/'+showPostLabel+'">More</a>');
  }

  /*** LET'S STOP THE POST LIST ***/
  document.write('</ul>');

}

/*** LET'S SHOW THE POST AS RANDOM OR ELSE AS RECENT ***/
if (showRandomPosts == 'true')
{
  for (var i = 0; i < postCount ; i++)
  {
  GenerateNum();
  document.write('<script src="https://'+domainURL+'/feeds/posts/default/-/'+showPostLabel+'?alt=json-in-script&start-index='+RandomNum+'&max-results=1&callback=jsonposts"></'+'script>')
  }
}
else 
{
  document.write('<script src="https://'+domainURL+'/feeds/posts/default/-/'+showPostLabel+'?alt=json-in-script&callback=jsonposts"></'+'script>');
}
```

Is is the same code with `domainURL` and `showPostLabel` settings changed so it can be properly tested.

```js
  /*** LET'S ADD THE VARIABLE SETINGS. TO TOGGLE USE TRUE/FALSE ***/
  var domainURL = "www.mybloggertricks.com";
  var className = "default";
  var postCount = 3;
  var showPostLabel = "Widgets";
  var showPostContentAmount = 160;
  var showPostTitle = "true";
  var showPostTitleAmount = 80;
  var showInPostImageSize = 320;
  var showPostComments = "true";
  var showPostDate = "true";
  var showPostAuthor = "true";
  var showPostImage = "true";
  var showPostCategory = "true";
  var showPostTags = "true";
  var showPostContent = "true";
  var showCategoryArchive = "true";
  var showRandomPosts = "true";

  /*** LET'S GENERATE RANDOM POSTS ***/
  if (showRandomPosts == 'true')
  {
    var RandomArray = [];
    var TotalPosts  = 0;
    var RandomArray = new Array(postCount);

    function TotalCount(json)
    {
      TotalPosts   = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;
    }
    document.write('<script src="https://'+domainURL+'/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=TotalCount"></'+'script>');

    function GenerateNum()
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < postCount ; i++)
      {
        for (var j = 0; j < RandomArray.length; j++)
        {
          var RandomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (TotalPosts ) + 1);
          RandomArray[i] = RandomNum;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /*** LET'S START THE POST LIST ***/
  function jsonposts(json)
  {
    document.write('<ul class="json-posts '+className+'">');
    for (var i = 0; i < postCount; i++)
    {
      /*** LET'S DECLARE VARIABLES ***/
      var postVariables= postImage = postUrl = postTitle = postImage = postContent = postArticle = postAuthor = postLabel = postDate = postUpdated = postComment = postImageURL = postCategoryArchive = postImageURLSize = postAuthorImage = postDateFormat = Y = D = M = m = YY = DD = MM = mm = TT =  "";

      /*** LET'S GET THE POST LABELS ***/
      if (json.feed.entry[i].category != null)
      {
        for (var k = 0; k < json.feed.entry[i].category.length; k++)
        {
          postLabel += '<a class="json-post-article-tags-item" href="'+domainURL+'/search/label/'+json.feed.entry[i].category[k].term+'">'+json.feed.entry[i].category[k].term+'</a>';
          if(k < json.feed.entry[i].category.length-1)
          {
            postLabel += '<span class="json-post-article-tags-item-seperator">, </span>';
          }
        }
      }

      /*** LET'S GET THE POST URL ***/
      for (var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++)
      {
        if (json.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate')
        {
          break;
        }
      }
      postUrl= '"' + json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href + '"';

      /*** LET'S GET THE POST INFO ***/
      postCategoryArchive = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;

      /*** LET'S GET THE POST TITLE ***/
      if (json.feed.entry[i].title!= null)
      {
        postTitle= json.feed.entry[i].title.$t.substr(0, showPostTitleAmount);
      }

      /*** LET'S GET THE POST COMMENT COUNT ***/
      if (json.feed.entry[i].thr$total)
      {
        postComment= '<a href="'+json.feed.entry[i].link[j].href+'#comment-form">'+json.feed.entry[i].thr$total.$t+'</a>';
      }

      /*** LET'S GET THE POST AUTHOR INFO ***/
      postAuthor= json.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t.split(' ');
      postAuthor=postAuthor.slice(0, 1).join(' ');
      postAuthorImage = json.feed.entry[i].author[0].gd$image.src;

      /*** LET'S GET THE POST CONTENT ***/
      postArticle = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
      postContent= postArticle.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,'').substring(0, showPostContentAmount);

      /*** LET'S FORMAT THE POST DATE MONTH ***/
      postDateFormat= ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

      /*** LET'S GET THE POST DATE ***/
      postDate= json.feed.entry[i].published.$t.substring(0,10);

      /*** LET'S DO THE POST DATE FORMAT ***/
      Y = postDate.substring(0, 4);
      m = postDate.substring(5, 7);
      D = postDate.substring(8, 10);
      M = postDateFormat[parseInt(m - 1)];

      /*** LET'S GET THE UPDATED POST DATE ***/
      postUpdated= json.feed.entry[i].updated.$t.substring(0, 16);

      /*** LET'S DO THE UPDATED POST DATE FORMAT ***/
      YY = postUpdated.substring(0, 4);
      mm = postUpdated.substring(5, 7);
      DD = postUpdated.substring(8, 10);
      TT = postUpdated.substring(11, 16);
      MM = postDateFormat[parseInt(mm - 1)];

      /*** LET'S GET THE POST IMAGE ***/
      if (json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail)
      {
        postImageURL = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
        postImageURLSize= postImageURL.replace("/s72-c/","/s"+showInPostImageSize+"/");
        postImage= "'" + postImageURLSize.replace("?imgmax=800","") + "'";
      }

      /*** LET'S ADD VARIOUS IMAGE TYPE SUPPORT***/
      else if (json.feed.entry[i].content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/) != null)
      {
        postImage =  json.feed.entry[i].content.$t.match(/src=(.+?[\.jpg|\.gif|\.png]")/)[1];
      }

      /*** LET'S OPEN THE POST ARTICLE ***/
      document.write('<li class="json-post-article-'+[i]+'">');

      /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST CATEGORY ***/
      if (showPostCategory == 'true')
      {
        document.write('<div class="json-post-article-tags"><span class="json-post-article-tags-label"></span>'+postLabel+'</div>');
      }

      /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST IMAGE ***/
      if (showPostImage == 'true')
      {
        document.write('<a class="json-post-article-featured-image-link" href="'+postUrl+'"><figure class="json-post-article-featured-image" style="background: url('+postImage+') no-repeat center center / cover !important"></figure></a>');
      }

      /*** LET'S OPEN THE POST INFO BOX ***/
      document.write('<div>');

      /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST TITLE ***/
      if (showPostTitle == 'true')
      {
        document.write('<h4 class="json-post-article-title"><a class="json-post-article-title-link" href="'+postUrl+'">'+postTitle+'</a></h4>');
      }

      /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST AUTHOR ***/
      if (showPostAuthor == 'true')
      {
        document.write('<span class="json-post-article-author-label"></span><figure class="json-post-article-author-avatar" style="background: url(https:'+postAuthorImage+') no-repeat center center /cover !important"></figure><span class="json-post-article-author-avatar">'+postAuthor+'</span>');
      }

      /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST DATE ***/
      if (showPostDate == 'true')
      {
        document.write('<div class="json-post-article-date"><span class="json-post-article-date-label"></span><span class="json-post-article-date-month">'+M+'</span> <span class="json-post-article-date-day">'+D+'</span> <span class="json-post-article-date-year">'+Y+'</span></div>');
      }

      /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST CONTENT ***/
      if (showPostContent == 'true')
      {
        document.write('<p class="json-post-article-content">'+postContent+'...</p>');
      }

      /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST TAGS ***/
      if (showPostTags == 'true')
      {
        document.write('<div class="json-post-article-tags"><span class="json-post-article-tags-label"></span>'+postLabel+'</div>');
      }

      /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST COMMENT COUNT ***/
      if (showPostComments == 'true')
      {
        document.write('<div class="json-post-article-comment-count"><span class="json-post-article-comment-count-label">Comments: </span><span class="json-post-article-comment-count-number">'+postComment+'</span></div>');
      }

      /*** LET'S CLOSE THE POST INFO BOX ***/
      document.write('</div>');

      /*** LET'S CLOSE THE POST ARTICLE ***/
      document.write('</li>');

    }

    /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST CATEGORY ARCHIVE LINK ***/
    if (showCategoryArchive == 'true')
    {
      document.write('<a class="json-post-article-category-more" href="'+domainURL+'/search/label/'+showPostLabel+'">More</a>');
    }

    /*** LET'S STOP THE POST LIST ***/
    document.write('</ul>');

  }

  /*** LET'S SHOW THE POST AS RANDOM OR ELSE AS RECENT ***/
  if (showRandomPosts == 'true')
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < postCount ; i++)
    {
    GenerateNum();
    document.write('<script src="https://'+domainURL+'/feeds/posts/default/-/'+showPostLabel+'?alt=json-in-script&start-index='+RandomNum+'&max-results=1&callback=jsonposts"></'+'script>')
    }
  }
  else
  {
    document.write('<script src="https://'+domainURL+'/feeds/posts/default/-/'+showPostLabel+'?alt=json-in-script&callback=jsonposts"></'+'script>');
  }
```

FYI: if `showRandomPosts` is set to `false`, then the script works fine.

Comment: RandomNum is only scoped inside the function GenerateNum(). Outside that function it doesn't exist

Comment: Too much code that doesn’t matter. Ensure problems present a “minimal” reproduction - building such a reproduction can often identify the issue itself.

Comment: @charlietfl has provided you with the answer. Scoping is the problem here... you're using a function scoped variable outside of that scope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FYI: if showRandomPosts is set to true, then the script works fine.

Your function `RandomNum()` is inside of that `if` statement which causes your function to only execute when `showRandomPosts = true`

But if I am understanding correctly you only want to show random posts if your variable is true. If you want to continiously use the `RandomNum()` function you could just remove your `if` statement under `/*** LET'S GENERATE RANDOM POSTS ***/`

Comment: I meant to say if it was set to false, not true. Anyway, I understand why you say it doesn't work. That makes sense. However, I do not understand  how to make post random as optional.